# Is it possible to use localStorage and window.openDatabase in Adobe AIR?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, air, local-storage, offlineapps

I have a working offline application (`.html` + `.js`). It uses localStorage and an SQLite database accessed using the `openDatabase` method. however, when I try to convert this to Adobe AIR using the Adobe Air Debug Launcher, it does not seem to work.

I also get the following errors from command line:

```
"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: localStorage"
```

Is Adobe AIR not HTML5 compliant? If it's not supporting `localStorage` and `openDatabase()` - is it possible to just include another JS file to fix this?

My concern is that I want the application to work in the Google Chrome browser and Adobe AIR without having to make a lot of rewrites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe AIR doesn't support Web Storage, as it has its own local storage engine through the class `flash.data.EncryptedLocalStore` ([docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/data/EncryptedLocalStore.html)).

Take a look on this article to a [tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/ajax/articles/encrypted_local_store.html).

Comment: The API I've mentioned is SQLite based. It's also possible to connect to a SQLite DB, look at this http://appdeveloper.intel.com/en-us/blog/2011/01/17/sqlite-adobe-air

Comment: okay. thank you! looks like i really need to rewrite my codes.

Comment: You should only rewrite the data access layer. I didn't search yet, but if it does not exist, then you should create a DAO or some Data Access layer that abstract your data. Your application should only access this abstraction and you would have two versions of this layer only.